# How to convert/change sql trigger into MYSQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a `SQL trigger` and I want to convert it into `MYSQL trigger`.
Below is the code for my SQL trigger:

```
Create TRIGGER Trigger_INSERT_Student   
on [Student]    
   AFTER INSERT   
AS     
BEGIN    
        declare @S_Id int;
        declare @First_Name var char(255);
        declare @Last_Name var char (255);
        declare @Program var char (100) ;
        declare @GPA float ;
        declare @Birthday_date ;
        declare @Blood_Group var char(255) ;
        declare @Contact_Number var char (10);
        declare @Address var char(255) ;
        declare @City var char (255)    ;
        declare @Trigger_Action var char (255) ;


        select @S_Id=S_Id from inserted ;
        select @First_Name=First_Name from inserted ;
        select @Last Name=Last_Name from inserted ;
        select @Program=Program from inserted ;
        select @GPA=GPA  from inserted ;
        select @Birthday=Birthday from inserted ;
        select @Blood_Group=Blood_Group from inserted ;
        select @Contact Number=Contact_Number from inserted ;
        select @Address= Address from inserted ;
        select @City= City from inserted ;
        set @Trigger Action= 'Record Inserted';

        INSERT INTO Student History
        (S_Id,First_Name,Last_Name,Program,GPA,Birthday,Blood_Group,Contact_Number,Address,City,Trigger-Action)
        VALUES (@S_Id,@First-Name,@Last-Name,@Program,@GPA,@Birthday,@Blood_Group,@Contact_`enter code here`Number,@Address,@City,@Trigger Action)      
END
```

Can anyone help me converting this trigger in MYSQL trigger. Any suggestions are always welcome

Comment: [MySQL Triggers] https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php

Comment: This cannot work in sqlserver (inserted may contain many records). And all those selects are surely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    you can try like this in MySQL:


DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_insert_student $$

    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_student AFTER
    INSERT ON [Student]
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    INSERT
    IGNORE INTO student history (s_id, first_name, last_name, program, gpa, birthday, blood_group, contact_number, address, city, TRIGGER-action)
    VALUES (NEW.s_id,
            NEW.first_name,
            NEW.last_name,
            NEW.program,
            NEW.gpa,
            NEW.birthday,
            NEW.blood_group,
            NEW.contact_number,NEW.address,NEW.city,'Record Inserted') END $$ 
        DELIMITER ;
DELIMITER $$
```